# Enabling java modules for browsers

Tags: java, webbrowser-control

I have been struggling to run a interface that require java and says

> This module requires java to function, but your browser does not
>   support java

I have googled, installed jdk, and done the following steps

- mentioned allowed url in java control panel
- Looked into IE custom security setting but unable to find anything related to java stated [here](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml)
- Looked into firefox setting under add on but cannot find anything related to java as mentioned [here](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml)

I am a non java person, but it would be good to know why browser work with java after i instakked jdk and why it is such a hassle in general or for me to go around and making it work?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but the simple answer is: forget about using Java in your browser.

The technology to enable that ... would be [applets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet); but in short: that is dead end technology.

Chrome for example completely disabled Java support in their browsers; and it is not coming back.

So any efforts spend on your end to get something working might be futile; or at least: not long-lasting.

So the real answer is to step back and understand where that *need* to run Java code in a browser is coming from; and find ways around that.

Regarding the product you intend to use (webmin); it looks like they are now providing some HTML based replacement - see [here](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/HTML_File_Manager).

Comment: well i need the cpanel interface and pop me that msg. which i need in order for me to wor.

Comment: you mean my cpanel, it is private?

Comment: as i want to understand why, is the technology out of door with chrome and other browsers are following. The product is webmin

Comment: Just read the link I gave you. Java in browsers ... that is like **dead** for **years** almost. There were simply too many security problems and other legal quarrels.

Comment: Please see my updated answer; it looks like there is a replacement within webmin for that old java thing.

Comment: i don't see that in my sidebar of webmin. I detail, why was java disabled if i have to make a point?

Comment: Sorry, but I dont get your questions here. The IT world has **long** abandoned Java in browsers; there is nothing else to say here. Again; I TOLD you why; repeatedly; I gave you a link that shows more details. You can use any search engine and will find a ton of information about that ... so why do you want me to write down explicitly for you what was written down a thousand times before?